# Jquery. Call onchange handler function

Tags: jquery, onchange

In select I change option programmatically using jquery and then I want to call onchange action. I have this html code:

```
<select onchange="billing.newAddress(!this.value)" id="billing-address-select" name="billing_address_id">
   <option value="1">value1</option>
   <option value="2">value2</option>
   <option value="3">value3</option>
</select>
```

And javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#billing-address-select').change(function(e){
       if (sAddressType == 'school') {
        $("#billing-address-select option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
    $('#billing-address-select').trigger('change'); 
})(jQuery);
```

So, actually after loading page if condition is true, performed changin 'billing-address-select' and then calling onchange (billing.newAddress(!this.value)) action. But this action don`t call. where is mistake?

Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Comment: i see your selector has a few typos on this line   $("#billing-address-select option[value='2").attr("selected", "selected");      missing closing single quote ' and right square bracket ]   near option[value='2']"

Comment: btw `if (sAddressType = 'school')` is wrong, maybe you mean `sAddressType == 'school'`

Comment: and why do you have `onchange` event inline and in script.. why don't you write the things you required to do in one function rather than calling two change function for the same element..

Comment: @Joe: Thanks. It`s typo error